# bifacial.pvfactors_timeseries() TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: pvlib

I am trying to run the function: bifacial.pvfactors_timeseries(), and get the error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str'.

I am not sure which of my imput values is wrong. Bellow you can see the function how I have written it and afterwards all the input values.

```
        bifacial = pvlib.bifacial.pvfactors_timeseries(solar_azimuth=
                                                       interim_weather_df[cf.name_solar_azimuth_column],
                                                       solar_zenith=
                                                       interim_weather_df[cf.name_solar_zenith_column],
                                                       surface_azimuth=
                                                       interim_weather_df[cf.name_surface_azimuth_column],
                                                       surface_tilt=interim_weather_df[cf.name_surface_tilt_column],
                                                       axis_azimuth=self.axis_azimuth,
                                                       timestamps=interim_weather_df.index,
                                                       dni=interim_weather_df[cf.name_dni_column],
                                                       dhi=interim_weather_df[cf.name_dhi_column],
                                                       gcr=self.gcr,
                                                       pvrow_height=model.input_values.pv_row_height,
                                                       pvrow_width=model.input_values.pv_row_width,
                                                       albedo=model.input_values.albedo,
                                                       n_pvrows=3,
                                                       index_observed_pvrow=1,
                                                       rho_front_pvrow=0.03,
                                                       rho_back_pvrow=0.05,
                                                       horizon_band_angle=15.0)
```

Screenshots of the input structure:

[input solar azimuth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CT6HA.png), [input solar_zenith](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9GmN.png), [input surface_azimuth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWGXw.png), [input surface_tilt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OBbQ.png), [input timestamps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jngFV.png), [input dni](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVEH8.png), [input dhi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBIMs.png)

all other inputs are float and int.

I also tried to only use single numerical values as input and no DataFrames, as can be seen below. I still got the same error.

```
        bifacial = pvlib.bifacial.pvfactors_timeseries(solar_azimuth=235.7,
                                                       solar_zenith=75.6,
                                                       surface_azimuth=270,
                                                       surface_tilt=72.8,
                                                       axis_azimuth=180,
                                                       timestamps=datetime.datetime.strptime('01-01-2021  13:00:00', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'),
                                                       dni=29,
                                                       dhi=275,
                                                       gcr=0.2,
                                                       pvrow_height=2,
                                                       pvrow_width=2,
                                                       albedo=0.1,
                                                       n_pvrows=3,
                                                       index_observed_pvrow=1,
                                                       rho_front_pvrow=0.03,
                                                       rho_back_pvrow=0.05,
                                                       horizon_band_angle=15.0)
```

python version: 3.8.5
pvlib version: 0.8.0
pv factors version: 1.5.0
pandas version: 1.2.1

Does anyone know the solution for that error? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It is best to post the whole traceback of your error, not just the final error message.  That way you can see where in the code the error came from.  Can you please update your answer to include the traceback too?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I only had some interference between the anaconda and pip environment.